# Simulate mobile network in nodejs or javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, wap

I know this question sounds kinda dumb but I'll explain.

In Switzerland there is a law that for every competition there must be a free way to enter the competition. Normally that free way is WAP. This is easy. Just go on the internet with a mobile phone in a mobile network and type in the address. Now I want to build a bot that joins the (daily) competition automatically. But that will only work if the Website thinks you are in a mobile network. Is there any possible way to open the webpage with Nodejs/JavaScrip/Python with the page thinking it is mobile network when it actually isn't? Thanks in advance

Comment: If they are looking at HTTP headers, you could see what the phone is sending and duplicate those. If they are expecting the request to come from a known WAP proxy or mobile IP address, you are probably SOL.

Comment: Thanks. But how would I find out what headers a phone is sending. Being in the mobile network isn't enough, I still have to disguise my computer as an iPhone. But can you tell me how you would check what headers my computer sends? Or what the page is expecting?